# Heroku error in deploy R shiny app: there is no package called "plyr"

Tags: r, heroku, deployment, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app on heroku. The app uses some libraries and I added the command "library" at the top of the script for each library. However, whenever I try to deploy, the output returns a message with the text "there are no package called --package name--". Could someone indicate a possible solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary package(s) installed in your system before trying to load them?

Comment: Dear Bird, thanks for the reply. Yes, at the local host the app works perfectly. The problem occurs only after deployment.

Comment: Note that plyr has been superseded by dplyr and purrr.  Perhaps you could refactor your related code using those packages and reference those libraries.

Comment: Dear SteveM, thanks for the reply. I have already done this but the problem remains.

Comment: I know nothing about Heroku but here is an R install example: https://blog.rmhogervorst.nl/blog/2018/12/06/running-an-r-script-on-heroku/  If I read it right it requires that packages first be installed using the init.R script.  Hope that helps.